# Update fragment from parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that executes a method in the parent activity, and then if the conditions are right, the parent activity should update the fragment. But when doing that im getting this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment LoginFragment{426ebc40} not attached to Activity
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:620)
            at com.myapp.fragments.LoginFragment.setLoginFailed(LoginFragment.java:184)
            at com.myapp.activities.WelcomeActivity$7$1.run(WelcomeActivity.java:357)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code from the parent activity:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mSocket.off();
                            mSocket.disconnect();
//this call causes the crash
                            loginFragment.setLoginFailed();
                        }
                    });
```

Here is how i init the fragment from the parent activity:

```
public void showLoginFragment(String carrierName, ArrayList<CheckOperator> supportedCarriers, boolean carrierIsSupported) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top, R.anim.abc_slide_in_top, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable(IntentConstants.OPERATORS, supportedCarriers);
        b.putString(IntentConstants.OPERATOR_NAME, carrierName);
        b.putBoolean(IntentConstants.OPERATOR_SUPPORTED, carrierIsSupported);
        b.putString(IntentConstants.TOKEN, token);
        b.putString(IntentConstants.MMAIL, mMail);
        loginFragment.setArguments(b);
        ft.replace(R.id.welcome_fragment_container, loginFragment, "login");
        ft.commit();

        writePrefs().putString(Constants.CARRIER_NAME, carrierName).apply();
    }
```

Here is the code in the fragment:

```
  public void setLoginFailed() {
        weNeedTxt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_color));
        weNeedTxt.setText(getString(R.string.user_pass_error));
    }
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more information about your code? How is your fragment instantiated and added/attached to the main view?

Comment: @gabowsky question updated

Comment: How your logging in logic looks like? The reason of this is that your fragment hasn't been attached to any Context, so it could not execute getResources method as well as its views are all null. I want to see how you do the login part and where it returns a failed that require you to update your fragment.